# HTML/CSS intermediate bugs .hover/nav bug, @media bug, nav/aside CIS122

Tags: html, css, web

The website which my example/code is hosted on for better/easier access:

https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-2/hw2html.html

The link to my code/example on Tryit Editor on W3school:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVH30WWEAH8R

So here it goes, when you click that link that host my example/code you will see on the nav there is two links/.hover, this links to my last assignment and my current assignment. But when you hover over it you will see that to the far right of the box only a part of it is actually lit up.

[image: As you see the entire box isn't dark red]

I'm trying to solve this so the entire thing is dark red, now what I realized was the text decides how much of the box gets filled up, if the text is smaller (like just "client") the .hover is much smaller. I'm also trying to fix this issue which is very similar but I don't know if the code that might work for the first question will work for this one, below is the picture of what I am talking about.

When I hover over it now (when the screen is smaller than 700px it does that) How can I make it so the entire bar gets filled up instead of just the small box you see in the picture, this also causes me a huge conundrum because I tried making the text "Client Server" and "Hosting Domain" centered whenever it goes on top of the screen like that but it doesn't work, I don't understand how I can make it centered only when the screen is smaller than 700px (which makes it go on top instead of on the side)

[image: Example of the entire bar not being filled]

[image: A larger picture in case you needed it]

I just started getting into HTML/CSS a few weeks ago and I'm still very much learning it. Also do you think I should keep the nav on the side where it currently is or change it where it stays on the top like it does when its under 700px, I'm not sure what is nicer and any ideas are appreciated as I'm  still trying to figure out what looks the nicest.

(You'll also see when the page is under 700px the profile tab goes to the bottom where it looks terrible, I'm currently trying to fix that so maybe it goes under the nav but that's another bug for another time so do ignore that or just give me a tip but please not an answer as I'm trying to figure out how to do it myself).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

#CIS {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: darkred solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget,
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (min-width: 700px) {
  section {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }
  nav {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
  }
}

.navbase1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbase1 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbase1 a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

.navbase {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbase a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbase a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

#sub {
  color: Ivory;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#sub3 {
  color: Ivory;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#DN {
  text-align: center;
}

#PDN {
  text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  text-align: center;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

table {
  border: none;
}

#GD {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#HG {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#NC {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#price {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#TLD {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#musicsale {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#musicsaleinfo {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#bluehost {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#list-1 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-2 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-3 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-4 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

#list1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

#list2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list6 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list7 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list8 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list9 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list10 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list11 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list12 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

aside ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

aside ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
}

aside a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 80;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

aside a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

aside ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

aside ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

aside ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}

#title1 {
  height: 1px;
}

#GDtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#HGtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#NCtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#WDN {
  height: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Homework #2: HTML, CSS, Semantic and Responsive Page Layout, Domain Names, and Web Hosting</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Homework #1: HTML and Client-Server Technology">
  <meta name="keywords" content="technology, HTML, CSS, server, client">
  <meta name="author" content="Joe Cline">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hw2style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="CIS">CIS 122 Projects</h1>
  </header>

  <!--
    metatags-noindex robots.txt
    -->

  <nav id="nav" style="background:black;">
    <div class="navbase">
      <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-1/HTML-1.html">Client Server</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbase1">
      <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-2/hw2html.html">Hosting Domain</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <h2 id="DN">Domain Names and Web Hosting</h2>
    <h3 id="WDN"></h3>
    <table align="center" border="3">
      <tr>
        <th><a href="https://www.godaddy.com/" id="GD">GoDaddy</a></th>
        <th><a href="https://www.hostgator.com/" id="HG">HostGator</a></th>
        <th><a href="https://www.namecheap.com/" id="NC">NameCheap</a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="GDtd">GoDaddy is a domain registrar and web hosting service, known for their cheap domain names and their web hosting service that they offer.</td>
        <td id="HGtd">HostGator is a web hosting service and provider of shared, reseller, VPS. They include all of the following: Cloud Hosting/WordPress Hosting/VPS Hosting/Dedicated Hosting.</td>
        <td id="NCtd">NameCheap is an ICANN-accredited registrar, they provide domain name registration and web hosting.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="price">If your interested in buying a .com web domain from GoDaddy, the prices are the following: For 5 years it would cost you $62.95, the price is $2.99 for the first year and $14.99 for every year after that.</p>
    <p id="musicsale">The domain name musicsales.com was bought using the service: Network Solutions, LLC. The domain name expires on 2021-08-24 </p>
    <p id="musicsaleinfo">If you want to buy the domain name musicsales.info it could cost you around $4.88, some websites like GoDaddy/NameCheap charges cheaper but they force you to get a plan </p>

    <table align="center" border="3" id="TLD">
      <caption class="title" id="title1"> <b>Newer TLDs of 2018</b>
        <tr>
          <td>.basketball</td>
          <td>.book</td>
          <td>.luxe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>.fan</td>
          <td>.arab</td>
          <td>.broker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>.hotel</td>
          <td>.phd</td>
          <td>.scholarships</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="bluehost">Webhosting at Bluehost.com will cost around $2.95/month*, this could vary though. The orginal starting price was $7.99, this changed to $3.95 and then changed again to it's final price of $2.95/month* </p>

    <ol id="list-1">
      <li>
        <p id="list1">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list2">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list3">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ul id="list-2">
      <li>
        <p id="list4">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list5">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list6">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ol id="list-3">
      <li>
        <p id="list7">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list8">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list9">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="list-4">
      <li>
        <p id="list10">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list11">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list12">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>

  </section>

  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Profiles</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Profile/2260402#_=_">Sololearn</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com/JosephCline">GitHub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <sub id="sub">CIS 122 Web Internet Technologies </sub>
    <br />
    <sub id="sub3">Copyright &copy; 2018 Joe Cline </sub>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Link to your site is currently not working (Vienna, Austria)

Comment: A few bits of helpful posting advice: (1) editors do not (should not) be credited for their amendments - this info [is in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52436757/revisions) so it does not need to go into the question.

Comment: (2) your questions have a great prior effort, but they are far too wordy for this platform. How frustrated you are, how easy readers think the question, whether a duplicate might exist, how appreciative you are, how much searching you've done, what voting people might be tempted to do, are all immaterial to the question. Don't worry if you get the odd downvote - it happens, and if you participate here, you'll get more upvotes then downvotes. Indeed, asking people not to downvote can result in downvotes!

Comment: My advice is to ask succinct, [confident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) questions. (3) questions are for posterity here, so try to keep it focussed on one thing, so try to avoid "incidentally also" sections that try to ask  another question - that is better in a separate post.

Comment: (4) posts are often closed for relying on external links, since links frequently break, which causes clean-up or deletion work for volunteer janitors. Your questions seem to have survived the cull, since they contain code as well as links, but try to avoid links at all, except in an "additional" capacity at the end (e.g. JS Fiddle or code runner links). Hope this helps `:=)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first Question give .navbase1 a:hover and .navbase a:hover{ width:100%} and that will fix the gap problem and will make your links centered.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

#CIS {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: darkred solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget,
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (min-width: 700px) {
  section {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }
  nav {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
  }
}

.navbase1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbase1 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbase1 a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
  width:100%;
}

.navbase {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbase a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbase a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
  width:100%;
}

#sub {
  color: Ivory;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#sub3 {
  color: Ivory;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#DN {
  text-align: center;
}

#PDN {
  text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  text-align: center;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

table {
  border: none;
}

#GD {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#HG {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#NC {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#price {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#TLD {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#musicsale {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#musicsaleinfo {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#bluehost {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#list-1 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-2 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-3 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-4 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

#list1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

#list2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list6 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list7 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list8 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list9 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list10 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list11 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list12 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

aside ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

aside ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
}

aside a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 80;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

aside a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

aside ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

aside ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

aside ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}

#title1 {
  height: 1px;
}

#GDtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#HGtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#NCtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#WDN {
  height: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Homework #2: HTML, CSS, Semantic and Responsive Page Layout, Domain Names, and Web Hosting</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Homework #1: HTML and Client-Server Technology">
  <meta name="keywords" content="technology, HTML, CSS, server, client">
  <meta name="author" content="Joe Cline">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hw2style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="CIS">CIS 122 Projects</h1>
  </header>

  <!--
    metatags-noindex robots.txt
    -->

  <nav id="nav" style="background:black;">
    <div class="navbase">
      <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-1/HTML-1.html">Client Server</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbase1">
      <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-2/hw2html.html">Hosting Domain</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <h2 id="DN">Domain Names and Web Hosting</h2>
    <h3 id="WDN"></h3>
    <table align="center" border="3">
      <tr>
        <th><a href="https://www.godaddy.com/" id="GD">GoDaddy</a></th>
        <th><a href="https://www.hostgator.com/" id="HG">HostGator</a></th>
        <th><a href="https://www.namecheap.com/" id="NC">NameCheap</a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="GDtd">GoDaddy is a domain registrar and web hosting service, known for their cheap domain names and their web hosting service that they offer.</td>
        <td id="HGtd">HostGator is a web hosting service and provider of shared, reseller, VPS. They include all of the following: Cloud Hosting/WordPress Hosting/VPS Hosting/Dedicated Hosting.</td>
        <td id="NCtd">NameCheap is an ICANN-accredited registrar, they provide domain name registration and web hosting.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="price">If your interested in buying a .com web domain from GoDaddy, the prices are the following: For 5 years it would cost you $62.95, the price is $2.99 for the first year and $14.99 for every year after that.</p>
    <p id="musicsale">The domain name musicsales.com was bought using the service: Network Solutions, LLC. The domain name expires on 2021-08-24 </p>
    <p id="musicsaleinfo">If you want to buy the domain name musicsales.info it could cost you around $4.88, some websites like GoDaddy/NameCheap charges cheaper but they force you to get a plan </p>

    <table align="center" border="3" id="TLD">
      <caption class="title" id="title1"> <b>Newer TLDs of 2018</b>
        <tr>
          <td>.basketball</td>
          <td>.book</td>
          <td>.luxe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>.fan</td>
          <td>.arab</td>
          <td>.broker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>.hotel</td>
          <td>.phd</td>
          <td>.scholarships</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="bluehost">Webhosting at Bluehost.com will cost around $2.95/month*, this could vary though. The orginal starting price was $7.99, this changed to $3.95 and then changed again to it's final price of $2.95/month* </p>

    <ol id="list-1">
      <li>
        <p id="list1">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list2">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list3">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ul id="list-2">
      <li>
        <p id="list4">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list5">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list6">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ol id="list-3">
      <li>
        <p id="list7">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list8">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list9">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="list-4">
      <li>
        <p id="list10">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list11">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list12">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>

  </section>

  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Profiles</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Profile/2260402#_=_">Sololearn</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com/JosephCline">GitHub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <sub id="sub">CIS 122 Web Internet Technologies </sub>
    <br />
    <sub id="sub3">Copyright &copy; 2018 Joe Cline </sub>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```